# Numpy random array from 0 to 99, including both

Tags: python, numpy, random

I'm trying to create a np array with size (80,10) so each row has random values with range 0 to 99.

I've done that by

```
np.random.randint(99, size=(80, 10))
```

But I would like to always include both 0 and 99 as values in each row.

So two values in each row are already defined and the other 8 will be random.

How would I accomplish this? Is there a way to generate an array size (80,8) and just concatenate [0,99] to every row to make it (80,10) at the end?

Comment: Do you require 0 and 99 to be unique for each row or are duplicates from the other 8 values allowed?

Comment: Easier to just create all the entries randomly then replace them:  `arx[:,8] = 0`, `arx[:,9] = 99`.

Comment: @Reti43 Right, I'm looking to do it without any duplicates in the other 8

Comment: @TimRoberts I guess still generate with length 10 and just replace the last two values?

Comment: You could generate a matrix with random values **not** including 0 and 99. Then replace random indices with 0 and 99 as suggested above.

Comment: I'm thinking that's easiest.  In a truly random list, you're going to get duplicates, but I suppose you could use `np.random.randint(1,98,size=(80,10))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments by Tim, you can generate a matrix with random values not including `0` and `99`. Then replace two random indices along the second axis with the values `0` and `99`.

```
rand_arr = np.random.randint(low=1, high=98, size=(80, 10))
rand_indices = np.random.rand(80,10).argsort(axis=1)[:,:2]
np.put_along_axis(rand_arr, rand_indices, [0,99], axis=1)
```

The motivation for using `argsort` is that we want random indices along the second axis without replacement. Just generating a random integer matrix for values 0-10 with `size=(80,2)` will not guarantee this.

In your scenario, you could do `np.argpartion` with `kth=2` instead of `np.argsort`. This should be more efficient.

Comment: This is the best answer provided so far. The combination of argsort and put_along_axis is something that didn't occur to me. Unfortunately the OP went ahead and accepted an answer that explicitly doesn't account for duplicates, even though he stated he'd rather not have that.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried a few things and this is what I came up with

```
def generate_matrix(low, high, shape):
    x, y = shape
    values = np.random.randint(low+1, high-1, size=(x, y-2))
    predefined = np.tile([low, high], (x, 1))
    values = np.hstack([values, predefined])
    for row in values:
        np.random.shuffle(row)
    return values
```

Example usage

```
>>> generate_matrix(0, 99, (5, 10))
array([[94,  0, 45, 99, 18, 31, 78, 80, 32, 17],
       [28, 99, 72,  3,  0, 14, 26, 37, 41, 80],
       [18, 78, 71, 40, 99,  0, 85, 91,  8, 59],
       [65, 99,  0, 45, 93, 94, 16, 33, 52, 53],
       [22, 76, 99, 15, 27, 64, 91, 32,  0, 82]])
```

---

**The way I approached it:**

Generate an array of size (80, 8) in the range [1, 98] and then concatenate 0 and 99 for each row. But you probably need the 0/99 to occur at different indices for each row, so you have to shuffle them. Unfortunately, `np.random.shuffle()` only shuffles the rows among themselves. And if you use `np.random.shuffle(arr.T).T`, or [`random.Generator.permutation`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.permutation.html), you don't shuffle the columns independently. I haven't found a vectorised way to shuffle the rows independently other than using a Python loop.

**Another way:**

You can generate an array of size (80, 10) in the range [1, 98] and then substitute in random indices the values 0 and 99 for each row. Again, I couldn't find a way to generate unique indices per row (so that 0 doesn't overwrite 99 for example) without a Python loop.  Since I couldn't find a way to avoid Python loops, I opted for the first way, which seemed more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about duplicates, create an array of zeros, replace columns 1-9 with random numbers and set column 10 to 99.

```
final = np.zeros(shape=(80, 10))
final[:,1:9] = np.random.randint(97, size=(80, 8))+1
final[:,9] = 99
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a matrix 80x10 with random values from 0 to 99  with no duplicates in the same row  with 0 and 99 included in every row

```
import random
row99=[ n for n in range(1,99) ]
perm = [n for n in range(0,10) ]
m = []
for i in range(80):
    random.shuffle(row99)      
    random.shuffle(perm)
    
    r = row99[:10]
    r[perm[0]] = 0
    r[perm[1]] = 99

    m.append(r)
    
print(m)
```

Partial output:

```
[
   ... other elements here ...
[70, 58, 0, 25, 41, 10, 90, 5, 42, 18], 
[0, 57, 90, 71, 39, 65, 52, 24, 28, 77], 
[55, 42, 7, 9, 32, 69, 90, 0, 64, 2], 
[0, 59, 17, 35, 56, 34, 33, 37, 90, 71]]
```

Comment: There's no reason to use loops in a numpy solution, but this is the right idea

Comment: i agree but , np.random.randint(0,10, size=(10,10)) give us duplicates in the same row .   so currently i don't see any solution without duplicates except mine.

Comment: @Reti43 now both 0 and 99 are present